# Running fortran code from shell doesn't work

Tags: linux, shell

I want to run some fortran code from a shell script on CentOS linux. I compiled the fortran file like this: `gfortran -ffixed-line-length-none -O3 -o fortran_file.x fortran_file.f` and then, in a .scr file I have this line of code: `timeout {$maxtime}s fortran_file.x`, where maxtime is passed as an external parameter. The code worked well on another computer, so i am quite confident I have no (major) bug, but when I run my .scr code as `./code.scr` I am getting this error: `timeout: failed to run command ‘fortran_file.x’: No such file or directory`, althoug the `fortran_file.x` is obviously in the same directory as my .scr code. Does anyone know how can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Does using `./fortran_file.x` instead work?

Comment: yes, that works.

Comment: @Shawn it seems that even just running timeout 2s fortran_file.x give this error: timeout: failed to run command ‘fortran_file.x’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

The program `timeout` will just perform the command that you give it:

```
NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
       timeout [OPTION]

DESCRIPTION
       Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
```

Your command is simply

```sh
fortran_file.x
```

This will start your program only when it can be found in the executable search path (`$PATH`). Apparently, this is not the case. So you either need to add your working directory to `$PATH`,

```sh
export PATH="$(pwd):$PATH"
```

or, better, just use `./` to refer to a program in your working directory,

```sh
timeout {$maxtime}s ./fortran_file.x
```

If your original line worked in some other system, it must have been either because the working directory was in `$PATH`, or due to some rather atypical shell that interpreted the command to your expectations (Windows do that, for instance).